# Listview error: parsing xml not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

Tried all that I could read on net but to no avail. Getting the above error on this fragment_main.xml code. I want to create a simple listview with some text in linear layout. Please point out the mistake.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/selection"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff0000cc"
android:textStyle="bold“ />
</TextView>

<ListView android:id="@android:id:listView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">    
</ListView>

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Empty set"/>
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 android:textStyle="bold“ />
 </TextView>
```

to

```
 android:textStyle="bold“ /> // this /> indicates the end of tag
```

Change this

```
 android:textStyle="bold“
```

to

```
android:textStyle="bold" // note the ""
```

Similarly for other textview

```
android:text="@string/Empty set"/>
</TextView>
```

Change to

```
android:text="@string/Empty set"/>
```

Finally

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000cc"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Empty set" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note : **fill_parent (renamed match_parent in API Level 8) tells your view to become as big as its parent view group will allow.**

So use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`.